# Why does appending to a python list set its type to None

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iterator, append, typeerror

I've looked through the rest of Stack Exchange and found questions that are similar, but not the same as mine and not helped.

My code is as follows:

```
class star:
    def __init__(self):
        # irrelevant other variables
        self.planets = []

    def genPlanets(self):
        self.planets.append(random.uniform(self.frostLine*0.98, self.frostLine*1.02))
        print ("There is a planet at " + str(self.planets[0]) + " AU away from the star.")
```

This part of the code outputs the following to the console:

> []
>
> There is a planet at 2.916687900748318 AU away from the star.

However, in the next part of the code:

```
def genPlanets:
    # irrelevant, working code.

    planetSort = planets.sort()
    for p in planetSort:
        file.write("There is a planet at " + str(p) + " AU away from the star.")
```

It outputs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Dominic\Documents\Coding\The Galaxy Maker\MAin.py", line 145, in
>
> Star.outerHabitable, Star.innerPlanetary, Star.outerPlanetary, Star.frostLine, Star.planets)
>
> File "C:\Users\Dominic\Documents\Coding\The Galaxy Maker\MAin.py", line 125, in writeData
>
> for p in planetSort:
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I do not understand how this has happened and I don't see why the append function would return a None type! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def genPlanets:
    # irrelevant, working code.

    planets.sort()
    for p in planets:
        file.write("There is a planet at " + str(p) + " AU away from the star.")
```

The .sort() method transforms the object you apply it to instead of returning the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

> def genPlanets:
>       # irrelevant, working code.
>
> ```
> planetSort = planets.sort()
> for p in planetSort:
>     file.write("There is a planet at " + str(p) + " AU away from the star."
> ```

Here, planetSort was nothing because you didn't specify values to planets for sorting, hence the error showed it was 'NoneType'.

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns None, while `list.sorted()` does what you expected.

Either call `sort()` and use the original, now sorted list:

```py
planets.sort()
for p in planets:
    ...
```

Or use the `sorted()` function instead:

```py
planetSort = planets.sorted()
for p in planetSort:
    ...
```